# Error generating X.509 certificate in Go

Tags: go, x509certificate

I'm new using Go and I'm trying to generate an X.509 certificate using this code:

```
cert, err := x509.CreateCertificate(
    random,
    &certTemplate,
    cert,
    publicKey,
    privateKey
)
```

where the publicKey variable is typed as interface{} and it is the result of calling x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(bytes).

The error I'm having is:

**x509: only RSA and ECDSA public keys supported**

I arrived to the conclusion that this is a consequence of passing the publicKey typed as interface{} to the x509.CreateCertificate function, since it doesn't match the type switch inside that function. I tried passing &publicKey with the same result. I also tried doing a type assertion using the publicKey, like this:

```
var pk *ecdsa.PublicKey
pk = publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)

cert, err := x509.CreateCertificate(
    random,
    &certTemplate,
    cert,
    pk,
    privateKey
)
```

but then I get this error: **panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *ecdsa.PublicKey** The same error occurs if I pass &pk as a parameter.

This is how I generate the public key:

```
// Generate key pair
curve := elliptic.P384()
privateKey := new(ecdsa.PrivateKey)
privateKey, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(curve, rand.Reader)
publicKey := &privatekey.PublicKey

// Obtain bytes from public key for communication using protobuf
publicKeyBytes, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(publicKey)

// Protobuf communication takes place here

receivedPublicKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(publicKeyBytes)

// verification of public key here (the verification ends successfully)
// populate X.509 template

// create certificate
certificate, err := x509.CreateCertificate(
    random,
    &certificateTemplate,
    certificate,
    receivedPublicKey,
    privateKey,
)
```

If someone can point me in the right direction or knows how to solve this issue it will be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you read the x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey function you'll note it already returns one of these three types (masked as an interface{}): &rsa.PublicKey, &dsa.PublicKey or &ecdsa.PublicKey, my guess is that your key is of the &dsa.PublicKey type and therefore cannot be used by the CreateCertificate function. If this is not the case I need to see how exactly you are generating your key to figure out the problem.

Comment: @hbejgel I added the generation of the public key with additional details in the question.

Comment: This should help: https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Comment: @voutasaurus thanks! I modify the code based on the link you provided and it worked. Could you answer the question with the link so I can accept it?

Comment: Might be related to the fact that x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(publicKey) expects a pointer to a public key struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crypto/tls` package contains a file called `generate_cert.go` which shows the proper and idiomatic way to generate a self signed certificate.

You can find it here:
https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Or by browsing the files in the tls package directory in the filesystem location where you installed Go.

There are a number of things that should be done correctly and short of enumerating them all, reading, running, modifying and understanding that code is the best way to get to grips with how to use the crypto packages when generating certs.

In particular be careful of what you pass in to the `x509.CreateCertificate` function as the public and private keys. In the crypto packages keys are of the `interface{}` type which happily and dangerously turns compile time type checks into runtime type checks.

Comment: That's a useful pointer, but it would be better if you also supplied specific advice to address the original question, or summarised the key points from that code in your answer. Otherwise, your answer is entirely dependent on that code sample and link remaining valid.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you but in this case that code is about as likely to remain valid as Go is likely to remain a supported programming language since it's included in the standard library and has had two very minor edits since 2014: https://github.com/golang/go/commits/master/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work doing something like this:

```
// Generate key pair
curve := elliptic.P384()
//privateKey := new(ecdsa.PrivateKey)
privateKey, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(curve, rand.Reader)
publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey
```

And the rest as exactly what you wrote, see if you can mirror this and make it work.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I think there is something with the protobuf that is not working correctly. Just to reduce the things to try, when you tried it, did you use protobuf? Or did you run it in a single main function?

Comment: I ran it as a single main function and received the full Certificate. But I don't think its a problem with protobuf, by the error you're getting its probably a problem in the bytes from the public key you are receiving from the protobuf. Make sure you are passing the correct slice of bytes.

Comment: I did the same, without protobuf and it worked, so probably I'm doing something wrong when obtaining the bytes from the public key. Thanks for your help! I will continue trying to make it work.